# ESP32 BLE Interface with MIT APP Inventor

Tags: android, esp32, app-inventor

```
I am trying to write this code which is interfaced with an app. I want the led and buzzer to turn on when a button is pressed and it should turn off when it goes above or below the angle specified in the code and turn on when its between the angles specified.
```

//Created by Rohan Dengle    /************************************************************************************************************  *******************************************Start of Song Things********************************************* *************************************************************************************************************/  #define NOTE_B0  31 #define NOTE_C1  33 #define NOTE_CS1 35 #define NOTE_D1  37 #define NOTE_DS1 39 #define NOTE_E1  41 #define NOTE_F1  44 #define NOTE_FS1 46 #define NOTE_G1  49 #define NOTE_GS1 52 #define NOTE_A1  55 #define NOTE_AS1 58 #define NOTE_B1  62 #define NOTE_C2  65 #define NOTE_CS2 69 #define NOTE_D2  73 #define NOTE_DS2 78 #define NOTE_E2  82 #define NOTE_F2  87 #define NOTE_FS2 93 #define NOTE_G2  98 #define NOTE_GS2 104 #define NOTE_A2  110 #define NOTE_AS2 117 #define NOTE_B2  123 #define NOTE_C3  131 #define NOTE_CS3 139 #define NOTE_D3  147 #define NOTE_DS3 156 #define NOTE_E3  165 #define NOTE_F3  175 #define NOTE_FS3 185 #define NOTE_G3  196 #define NOTE_GS3 208 #define NOTE_A3  220 #define NOTE_AS3 233 #define NOTE_B3  247 #define NOTE_C4  262 #define NOTE_CS4 277 #define NOTE_D4  294 #define NOTE_DS4 311 #define NOTE_E4  330 #define NOTE_F4  349 #define NOTE_FS4 370 #define NOTE_G4  392 #define NOTE_GS4 415 #define NOTE_A4  440 #define NOTE_AS4 466 #define NOTE_B4  494 #define NOTE_C5  523 #define NOTE_CS5 554 #define NOTE_D5  587 #define NOTE_DS5 622 #define NOTE_E5  659 #define NOTE_F5  698 #define NOTE_FS5 740 #define NOTE_G5  784 #define NOTE_GS5 831 #define NOTE_A5  880 #define NOTE_AS5 932 #define NOTE_B5  988 #define NOTE_C6  1047 #define NOTE_CS6 1109 #define NOTE_D6  1175 #define NOTE_DS6 1245 #define NOTE_E6  1319 #define NOTE_F6  1397 #define NOTE_FS6 1480 #define NOTE_G6  1568 #define NOTE_GS6 1661 #define NOTE_A6  1760 #define NOTE_AS6 1865 #define NOTE_B6  1976 #define NOTE_C7  2093 #define NOTE_CS7 2217 #define NOTE_D7  2349 #define NOTE_DS7 2489 #define NOTE_E7  2637 #define NOTE_F7  2794 #define NOTE_FS7 2960 #define NOTE_G7  3136 #define NOTE_GS7 3322 #define NOTE_A7  3520 #define NOTE_AS7 3729 #define NOTE_B7  3951 #define NOTE_C8  4186 #define NOTE_CS8 4435 #define NOTE_D8  4699 #define NOTE_DS8 4978 #define REST      0  // Take Me Out to the Ball Game, first 8 notes // Score available at https://www.pianosongdownload.com/Take%20Me%20Out%20to%20the%20Ball%20Game%20Sheet%20Music.pdf  // Song arrays contains arrays of size 2 (note, duration) const int ballGameIntro[][2] = {   {NOTE_C6, 2},{NOTE_C7, 4},{NOTE_A7, 4},{NOTE_G6, 4},{NOTE_E6, 4},{NOTE_G7, -2},{NOTE_D6, -2} }; int introCount = sizeof(ballGameIntro) / sizeof(ballGameIntro[0]);  const int ballGame[][2] = {   {NOTE_C5, 2}, {NOTE_C6, 4}, //1   {NOTE_A6, 4}, {NOTE_G5, 4}, {NOTE_E5, 4}, {NOTE_G6, -2}, {NOTE_D5, -2}, {NOTE_C5, 2}, {NOTE_C6, 4},   {NOTE_A5, 4}, {NOTE_G5, 4}, {NOTE_E5, 4}, {NOTE_G5, -1}, {NOTE_A5, 4}, {NOTE_GS5, 4}, {NOTE_A5, 4},   {NOTE_E5, 4}, {NOTE_F5, 4}, {NOTE_G5, 4}, {NOTE_A5, 2}, {NOTE_F5, 4}, {NOTE_D5, -2}, {NOTE_A5, 2},   {NOTE_A5, 4}, {NOTE_A5, 4}, {NOTE_B5, 4}, {NOTE_C6, 4}, {NOTE_D6, 4}, {NOTE_B5, 4}, {NOTE_A5, 4},   {NOTE_G5, 4}, {NOTE_E5, 4}, {NOTE_D5, 4}, {NOTE_C5, 2}, {NOTE_C6, 4}, {NOTE_A5, 4}, {NOTE_G5, 4},   {NOTE_E5, 4}, {NOTE_G5, -2}, {NOTE_D5, 2}, {NOTE_D5, 4}, {NOTE_C5, 2}, {NOTE_D5, 4}, {NOTE_E5, 4},   {NOTE_F5, 4}, {NOTE_G5, 4}, {NOTE_A5, 1}, {NOTE_A5, 4}, {NOTE_B5, 4}, {NOTE_C6, -2}, {NOTE_C6, -2},   {NOTE_C6, 4}, {NOTE_B5, 4}, {NOTE_A5, 4}, {NOTE_G5, 4}, {NOTE_FS5, 4}, {NOTE_G5, 4}, {NOTE_A5, -2},   {NOTE_B5, -2}, {NOTE_C6, -1} }; int noteCount = sizeof(ballGame) / sizeof(ballGame[0]);  const int sandstorm[][2] = {   {NOTE_B3, 16}, {NOTE_B3, 16}, {NOTE_B3, 16}, {NOTE_B3, 16}, {NOTE_B3, 16}, {REST, 16},   {NOTE_B3, 16}, {NOTE_B3, 16}, {NOTE_B3, 16}, {NOTE_B3, 16}, {NOTE_B3, 16}, {NOTE_B3, 16}, {NOTE_B3, 16}, {REST, 16},   {NOTE_E4, 16}, {NOTE_E4, 16}, {NOTE_E4, 16}, {NOTE_E4, 16}, {NOTE_E4, 16}, {NOTE_E4, 16}, {NOTE_E4, 16}, {REST, 16},   {NOTE_D4, 16}, {NOTE_D4, 16}, {NOTE_D4, 16}, {NOTE_D4, 16}, {NOTE_D4, 16}, {NOTE_D4, 16}, {NOTE_D4, 16}, {REST, 16},   {NOTE_A3, 16}, {NOTE_A3, 16}, {NOTE_B3, 16}, {NOTE_B3, 16}, {NOTE_B3, 16}, {NOTE_B3, 16}, {NOTE_B3, 16}, {REST, 16},   {NOTE_B3, 16}, {NOTE_B3, 16}, {NOTE_B3, 16}, {NOTE_B3, 16}, {NOTE_B3, 16}, {NOTE_B3, 16}, {NOTE_B3, 16}, {REST, 16},   {NOTE_E4, 16}, {NOTE_E4, 16}, {NOTE_B3, 16}, {NOTE_B3, 16}, {NOTE_B3, 16}, {NOTE_B3, 16}, {NOTE_B3, 16}, {REST, 16},   {NOTE_B3, 16}, {NOTE_B3, 16}, {NOTE_B3, 16}, {NOTE_B3, 16}, {NOTE_B3, 16}, {NOTE_B3, 16}, {NOTE_B3, 16}, {REST, 16},   {NOTE_E4, 16}, {NOTE_E4, 16}, {NOTE_B3, 16}, {NOTE_B3, 16}, {NOTE_B3, 16}, {NOTE_B3, 16}, {NOTE_B3, 16}, {REST, 16},   {NOTE_B3, 16}, {NOTE_B3, 16}, {NOTE_B3, 16}, {NOTE_B3, 16}, {NOTE_B3, 16}, {NOTE_B3, 16}, {NOTE_B3, 16}, {REST, 16},   {NOTE_E4, 16}, {NOTE_E4, 16}, {NOTE_E4, 16}, {NOTE_E4, 16}, {NOTE_E4, 16}, {NOTE_E4, 16}, {NOTE_E4, 16}, {REST, 16},   {NOTE_D4, 16}, {NOTE_D4, 16}, {NOTE_D4, 16}, {NOTE_D4, 16}, {NOTE_D4, 16}, {NOTE_D4, 16}, {NOTE_D4, 16}, {REST, 16},   {NOTE_A3, 16}, {NOTE_A3, 16}, {NOTE_B3, 16}, {NOTE_B3, 16}, {NOTE_B3, 16}, {NOTE_B3, 16}, {NOTE_B3, 16}, {REST, 16} }; int sandstormCount = sizeof(sandstorm) / sizeof(sandstorm[0]);  const int chargeIntro[][2] = {   {NOTE_B4, 4}, {NOTE_F4, 4},{NOTE_G4, 4}, {NOTE_A4, 4}, }; int chargeIntroCount = sizeof(chargeIntro) / sizeof(chargeIntro[0]);  const int chargeOutro[][2] = {   {NOTE_C5, -2},   {NOTE_G4, 8}, {NOTE_C5, 8},{NOTE_E5, 8}, {NOTE_G5, -8}, {NOTE_E5, 16}, {NOTE_G5, 2} }; int chargeOutroCount = sizeof(chargeOutro) / sizeof(chargeOutro[0]); /************************************************************************************************************  *******************************************End of Song Things*********************************************** *************************************************************************************************************/  #include <BLEDevice.h> #include <BLEServer.h> #include <BLEUtils.h> #include <BLE2902.h> #include <Adafruit_LIS3DH.h> #include <NoDelay.h>  BLECharacteristic *pCharacteristic; bool deviceConnected = false; float txValue = 0; const int readPin = 32; // Use GPIO number. See ESP32 board pinouts const int LED = 2; // Could be different depending on the dev board. I used the DOIT ESP32 dev board.  // Bluetooth Variables int angle   = 0; int angleSEL  = 0; int blastSEL    = 0; boolean soundSEL  = false; int lightSEL  = 0; boolean vibeSEL   = false; boolean buntMode  = true; boolean negFeed   = false; char checkValue = 0; boolean received = false;   unsigned long sleepTime = 0;  //PIN LOCATIONS #define GREEN_LED 16 #define YELLOW_LED 17 #define RED_LED 21 #define VIBRATE 9 const int BUZZER = 26; #define SOUND_OFF           0  #define degree_of_freedom 5  // We'll just choose PWM channel 0 here const int TONE_PWM_CHANNEL = 0;   // Non Blocking Delays noDelay sendAngle(300); noDelay blinkLED(400); boolean blinkState = true; noDelay trailLED(500); boolean greenState = true, yellowState = false, redState = false; noDelay noVelocity(125);  // Speed Variables long refresh_time, sampleRate; long startTime,timeOfSwing; double total_accel; double max_accel; double velocity; uint16_t peakVelocity; int count; int velocityCount;  uint16_t data;  // Function Declarations void error(const __FlashStringHelper*err); void playSong(int pin, int song[][2], int totalNotes, int tempo); void(* resetFunc) (void) = 0; //declare reset function @ address 0  #define SERVICE_UUID           "6E400001-B5A3-F393-E0A9-E50E24DCCA9E" // UART service UUID #define CHARACTERISTIC_UUID_RX "6E400002-B5A3-F393-E0A9-E50E24DCCA9E" #define CHARACTERISTIC_UUID_TX "6E400003-B5A3-F393-E0A9-E50E24DCCA9E"  // Create Accelerometer object Adafruit_LIS3DH lis = Adafruit_LIS3DH();  class MyServerCallbacks: public BLEServerCallbacks {     void onConnect(BLEServer* pServer) {       deviceConnected = true;    ledcWriteNote(TONE_PWM_CHANNEL, NOTE_B, 4);   delay(500);   ledcWriteNote(TONE_PWM_CHANNEL, NOTE_F, 4);   delay(500);   ledcWriteNote(TONE_PWM_CHANNEL, NOTE_G, 4);   delay(500);   ledcWriteNote(TONE_PWM_CHANNEL, NOTE_A, 4);   delay(500);    ledcWriteNote(TONE_PWM_CHANNEL, NOTE_B, 4);   delay(500);   ledcWriteNote(TONE_PWM_CHANNEL, NOTE_F, 4);   delay(500);   ledcWriteNote(TONE_PWM_CHANNEL, NOTE_G, 4);   delay(500);   ledcWriteNote(TONE_PWM_CHANNEL, NOTE_A, 4);   delay(500);    ledcWriteNote(TONE_PWM_CHANNEL, NOTE_C, 5);   delay(500);   ledcWriteNote(TONE_PWM_CHANNEL, NOTE_G, 4);   delay(500);   ledcWriteNote(TONE_PWM_CHANNEL, NOTE_C, 5);   delay(500);   ledcWriteNote(TONE_PWM_CHANNEL, NOTE_E, 5);   delay(500);   ledcWriteNote(TONE_PWM_CHANNEL, NOTE_G, 6);   delay(1000);   ledcWrite(TONE_PWM_CHANNEL, SOUND_OFF);   delay(500);      };      void onDisconnect(BLEServer* pServer) {       deviceConnected = false;     } };  class MyCallbacks: public BLECharacteristicCallbacks {     void onWrite(BLECharacteristic *pCharacteristic) {       std::string rxValue = pCharacteristic->getValue();        if (rxValue.length() > 0) {         Serial.println("*********");         Serial.print("Received Value: ");          for (int i = 0; i < rxValue.length(); i++) {           Serial.print(rxValue[i]);         }          Serial.println();          // Do stuff based on the command received from the app         if (rxValue.find("a") != -1) {            Serial.println("Turning ON!");           digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);         }         else if (rxValue.find("b") != -1) {           Serial.println("Turning OFF!");           digitalWrite(LED, LOW);         }           // Bat Logic   // Bunt Mode   /*if (buntMode) {     if (!negFeed) { */ // feedback when on target       if (rxValue.find("1") != -1 && (angle > 0) && (angle < 5) ) {           digitalWrite(GREEN_LED, HIGH);           ledcWriteNote(TONE_PWM_CHANNEL, NOTE_C, 5);           digitalWrite(VIBRATE,  (boolean) vibeSEL);           if (rxValue.find("A") != -1){             ledcWriteNote(TONE_PWM_CHANNEL, NOTE_C, 5);             //delay(500);           }           else{              ledcWrite(TONE_PWM_CHANNEL, SOUND_OFF);           }       } else       if (rxValue.find("2") != -1 && (angle > 15 - degree_of_freedom) && (angle < 15 + degree_of_freedom)) {           digitalWrite(YELLOW_LED, HIGH);               digitalWrite(VIBRATE,  (boolean) vibeSEL);           if (rxValue.find("A") != -1){             ledcWriteNote(TONE_PWM_CHANNEL, NOTE_C, 5);           }           else{             ledcWrite(TONE_PWM_CHANNEL, SOUND_OFF);           }         }        else       if (rxValue.find("3") != -1 && (angle > 45 - degree_of_freedom) && (angle < 45 + degree_of_freedom)) {           digitalWrite(RED_LED, HIGH);           digitalWrite(VIBRATE,  (boolean) vibeSEL);           if (rxValue.find("A") != -1){             ledcWriteNote(TONE_PWM_CHANNEL, NOTE_C, 5);           }           else{             ledcWrite(TONE_PWM_CHANNEL, SOUND_OFF);           }       }       else {         digitalWrite(GREEN_LED, LOW);         digitalWrite(YELLOW_LED, LOW);         digitalWrite(RED_LED, LOW);         digitalWrite(VIBRATE,  LOW);         ledcWrite(TONE_PWM_CHANNEL, SOUND_OFF);       }     }     if (negFeed) { // Feedback when off target       if (rxValue.find("1") != -1 && ((angle < 5 ) || (angle > 0))) {           digitalWrite(GREEN_LED, HIGH);           digitalWrite(VIBRATE,  (boolean) vibeSEL);           if (rxValue.find("A") != -1){             ledcWriteNote(TONE_PWM_CHANNEL, NOTE_A, 5);           }           else{             ledcWrite(TONE_PWM_CHANNEL, SOUND_OFF);           }       }       else if (rxValue.find("2") != -1 && ((angle < 15 - degree_of_freedom) || (angle > 15 + degree_of_freedom))) {           digitalWrite(YELLOW_LED, HIGH);             digitalWrite(VIBRATE,  (boolean) vibeSEL);           if (rxValue.find("A") != -1){             ledcWriteNote(TONE_PWM_CHANNEL, NOTE_A, 5);           }           else{             ledcWrite(TONE_PWM_CHANNEL, SOUND_OFF);           }               }       else if (rxValue.find("3") != -1 && ((angle < 45 - degree_of_freedom) || (angle > 45 + degree_of_freedom))) {           digitalWrite(RED_LED, HIGH);            digitalWrite(VIBRATE,  (boolean) vibeSEL);           if (rxValue.find("A") != -1){             ledcWriteNote(TONE_PWM_CHANNEL, NOTE_A, 5);           }           else{             ledcWrite(TONE_PWM_CHANNEL, SOUND_OFF);           }                }       else {         digitalWrite(GREEN_LED, LOW);         digitalWrite(YELLOW_LED, LOW);         digitalWrite(RED_LED, LOW);         digitalWrite(VIBRATE,  LOW);         ledcWrite(TONE_PWM_CHANNEL, SOUND_OFF);       }     }             Serial.println();         Serial.println("*********");       }      };  void setup() {   Serial.begin(115200);    ledcAttachPin(BUZZER, TONE_PWM_CHANNEL);   pinMode(LED, OUTPUT);   // PINS   pinMode(GREEN_LED, OUTPUT);   pinMode(YELLOW_LED, OUTPUT);   pinMode(RED_LED, OUTPUT);   pinMode(VIBRATE, OUTPUT);   pinMode(BUZZER, OUTPUT);    digitalWrite(GREEN_LED, LOW);   digitalWrite(YELLOW_LED, LOW);   digitalWrite(RED_LED, LOW);   digitalWrite(VIBRATE, LOW);    // Create the BLE Device   BLEDevice::init("Softball"); // Give it a name    // Create the BLE Server   BLEServer *pServer = BLEDevice::createServer();   pServer->setCallbacks(new MyServerCallbacks());    // Create the BLE Service   BLEService *pService = pServer->createService(SERVICE_UUID);    // Create a BLE Characteristic   pCharacteristic = pService->createCharacteristic(                       CHARACTERISTIC_UUID_TX,                       BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_NOTIFY                     );                          pCharacteristic->addDescriptor(new BLE2902());    BLECharacteristic *pCharacteristic = pService->createCharacteristic(                                          CHARACTERISTIC_UUID_RX,                                          BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_WRITE                                        );    pCharacteristic->setCallbacks(new MyCallbacks());    // Start the service   pService->start();    // Start advertising   pServer->getAdvertising()->start();   Serial.println("Waiting a client connection to notify...");  // Accelerometer Setup   Serial.println("LIS3DH test!");   if (! lis.begin(0x18)) {   // change this to 0x19 for alternative i2c address     Serial.println("Couldnt start");     while (1) yield();   }   Serial.println("LIS3DH found!");    lis.setDataRate(LIS3DH_DATARATE_LOWPOWER_5KHZ); }  void loop() {       if (deviceConnected) {      // Read Accelerometer   lis.read(); // Raw Value   sensors_event_t event; // In m/s^2   lis.getEvent(&event);    // Magnitude of all axis acceleration   total_accel = sq(event.acceleration.x) + sq(event.acceleration.y) + sq(event.acceleration.z);   total_accel = sqrt(total_accel);   // Subtract gravity   total_accel = abs(total_accel - 9.8);    // Calculate Swing Speed   if (micros() > sampleRate){     if (startTime == 0){       timeOfSwing = 0;       if (total_accel > 9){         startTime = millis();       }     }     else{       timeOfSwing = millis() - startTime;       if (total_accel > max_accel){         max_accel = total_accel;       }       if (total_accel < 9){         startTime = 0;         max_accel = 0;       }     }     sampleRate = micros() + 200;   }    velocity = max_accel*(timeOfSwing/1000.0)*2.237;      // Scale velocity up since accelerometer is not at tip of the bat   velocity*=1.2;      // Hold Peak Velocity   if ((velocity > peakVelocity) && (velocity < 100)){     peakVelocity = velocity;   }    // LED feedback from swing speed   if (peakVelocity > 10 && peakVelocity <= 40){     digitalWrite(GREEN_LED, HIGH);   }   else if (peakVelocity > 40 && peakVelocity <= 60){     digitalWrite(GREEN_LED, HIGH);     digitalWrite(YELLOW_LED, HIGH);   }   else if (peakVelocity > 60){     digitalWrite(GREEN_LED, HIGH);     digitalWrite(YELLOW_LED, HIGH);     digitalWrite(RED_LED, HIGH);   }    // Detects no movement for 5 seconds   if (noVelocity.update()){     if (velocity < 10){       velocityCount++;     }     else{       velocityCount = 0;     }   }   // Reset Peak Velocity to 0 and turn off LED if no movement   if (velocityCount >= 5){     velocityCount = 0;     peakVelocity = 0;     digitalWrite(GREEN_LED, LOW);     digitalWrite(YELLOW_LED, LOW);     digitalWrite(RED_LED, LOW);   }    // Calculate angle   if (sendAngle.update()){     angle = abs(57 * atan2 ((double) lis.x, (double) lis.z)); // this is the angle     if (checkValue != 0){       Serial.print(checkValue);       checkValue = 0;     }     else{       // Combine angle and speed into 1 integer to send via bluetooh       data = angle << 8;       data = data | peakVelocity;       Serial.print(data);     }   }        // Let's convert the value to a char array:     char txString[8]; // make sure this is big enuffz     dtostrf(data, 1, 0, txString); // float_val, min_width, digits_after_decimal, char_buffer          pCharacteristic->setValue(txString);          pCharacteristic->notify(data); // Send the value to the app!     Serial.print("*** Sent Value: ");     Serial.print(txString);     Serial.println(" ***");    }   delay(1000);   }     i am not able to get the output

Comment: Hi @Rohan, welcome to Stack Overflow. If you want help could you please properly format your code? You'll need to paste in properly indented code and then style it as code in the editor. As it is this is completely unreadable and incomprehensible.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.